# Two pages output instead of one

Tags: beamer

Why do I get two pages output with this code?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnote{$\lim\limits_{}$}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Using StefanH's approach I found a nice work-around to this behaviour. Just make a new line. Then the footnote as well as the footnotenumber is raised.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnote{$\lim\limits_{}$\\}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Strange indeed - it is the `\limits` command that seems to trigger this.

Comment: Add some text in the same frame, or a `\leavevmode` command.

Comment: @Bernard Adding text to the frame does not help

Comment: @Bernard Can you show an example, where to add the `\leavemode`?

Comment: For me it does. One can also replace `\limits` with `\displaystyle`. You can add `\leavevmode` anywhere (inside the frame, though ;o))

Comment: @samcarter: Sorry, I didn't check well: my viewer directly displays the slide with the footnote, but it's nevertheless  the second slide. For my excuse, the slide number is not as visible as for a standard class.

Comment: It seems to happen when somethings goes too deep below the baseline in the footnote. I get the same behavior for `Test\footnote{\raisebox{0pt}[10pt][6pt]{\rule{1pt}{16pt}}}`. But depth `5pt` is still on one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when the depth of the footnote is too large, so the contents goes outside the slide limit the whole page is flushed to the next. It can be seen by using a bar of depth `6pt`.

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  Test\footnote{\raisebox{-6pt}[10pt][6pt]{\rule{1pt}{16pt}}}
\end{frame}
```

A quick fix to trick LaTeX to believe the depth is 0 can be done by `\raisebox`. Still it is outside the page and not really visible. An alternative is to raise the footnote by its depth, but since the footnote number is not raised this is not perfect either.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test 1}
  Test\footnote{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{$\lim\limits_{a}$}}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test 2}
  Test\footnote{\raisebox{\depth}[\height+\depth][0pt]{$\lim\limits_{a}$}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]